# Como alterar os valores de um Hash?

Tags: ruby, dicionário

Preciso de um loop para alterar os valores desse objeto

```
{
    [ "Begin", "Dom" ] => 0,
    [ "Begin", "Seg" ] => 8,
    [ "Begin", "Ter" ] => 10,
    [ "Begin", "Qua" ] => 30,
    [ "Begin", "Qui" ] => 20,
    [ "Begin", "Sex" ] => 1,
    [ "Begin", "Sáb" ] => 0,
    [ "Finish", "Dom" ] => 0,
    [ "Finish", "Seg" ] => 1,
    [ "Finish", "Ter" ] => 0,
    [ "Finish", "Qua" ] => 0,
    [ "Finish", "Qui" ] => 0,
    [ "Finish", "Sex" ] => 0,
    [ "Finish", "Sáb" ] => 0
}
```

Preciso mudar os valores 0,8,10,30,20...

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modificando os valores

Primeiro armazene o `Hash` em uma variável

```
meu_hash = {
    [ "Begin", "Dom" ] => 0,
    [ "Begin", "Seg" ] => 8,
    [ "Begin", "Ter" ] => 10,
    [ "Begin", "Qua" ] => 30,
    [ "Begin", "Qui" ] => 20,
    [ "Begin", "Sex" ] => 1,
    [ "Begin", "Sáb" ] => 0,
    [ "Finish", "Dom" ] => 0,
    [ "Finish", "Seg" ] => 1,
    [ "Finish", "Ter" ] => 0,
    [ "Finish", "Qua" ] => 0,
    [ "Finish", "Qui" ] => 0,
    [ "Finish", "Sex" ] => 0,
    [ "Finish", "Sáb" ] => 0
}
```

Depois crie um loop para modificar os valores para o que quer que queira e pronto! Veja:

```
meu_hash.each_key do |key|
  meu_hash[key] = 5
end
```

Utilizei o `Hash#each_key` já que não precisei o `value` do `Hash` durante o loop. Se você for utilizar, use o `Enumerable#each` dessa forma:

```
meu_hash.each do |key, value|
  meu_hash[key] = value * 5
end
```

Também pode optar pelo `Enumerable#map`, mas não gosto dessa solução no `Hash`, já que não modifica ou retorna um `Hash`:

```
novo_hash = Hash[meu_hash.map {|key, value| [key, value * 5]}]
```

Essa forma é pura por não afetar o `meu_hash`, criando uma nova instância.

#### Deixando o código um pouco mais idiomático

Pode utilizar um atalho para criar um array de strings, o [`%w` ou `%W`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274675/what-does-warray-mean). Ficaria assim:

```
meu_hash = {
  %w[Begin Dom] => 0,
  %w[Begin Seg] => 8,
  %w[Begin Ter] => 10,
  %w[Begin Qua] => 30,
  %w[Begin Qui] => 20,
  %w[Begin Sex] => 1,
  %w[Begin Sáb] => 0,
  %w[Finish Dom] => 0,
  %w[Finish Seg] => 1,
  %w[Finish Ter] => 0,
  %w[Finish Qua] => 0,
  %w[Finish Qui] => 0,
  %w[Finish Sex] => 0,
  %w[Finish Sáb] => 0
}
```